# Uploading files below 200kb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, phusion

I am having trouble configuring modporter.

I have installed it correctly. I have no problems uploading files above 200kb.
But files below 200kb are not getting uploaded.
On upload of files below 200kb, its just saying "Application error
Rails application failed to start properly"
If I switch Porter off, it is getting uploaded.
There is no error log in apache error log or in the rails log.

Is there any min_file_upload_limit directive for porter?

I am using Rails 3.0.7, Apache and Phusion passenger.

Can anyone help me to find the error and to solve it.

Thanks.

Comment: modporter doesn't seem to be very current, last changes are from 2009, are you sure it's compatible with rails 3.0.x?

Comment: Yes. Its working for large files uploads. I'm Using Rails 3.0.7

Comment: If I remove the PorterDir in Apache conf, its working for upload of image files.

Comment: Now if I upload a other than image files its giving me "Errno::EPERM (Operation not permitted - /tmp/apreq"

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and also the answer to my own Qustion.
Its seems there is a permission issue.

I was able to fix the problem by making sure that Apache and the owner of the environment.rb were the same user. In my case, I changed the Apache run user to match the owner of environment.rb.

Change the User and Group option in Apache config file to match the owner of the environment.rb